# boost::signal slot_type with a template

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals

I'm getting a build error when  building for the following function:

```
template <class T> class Event {
public:
    typedef boost::signal<void (void*, const T)>    signal_t;
    typedef boost::signals::connection              connection_t;   

public:
    Event() { }

    connection_t connect(signal_t::slot_type subscriber){
        return signal.connect(subscriber);
    }
}
```

error:

```
error: 'class boost::signal<void ()(void*, T), boost::last_value<typename boost::function_traits<void ()(void*, T)>::result_type>, int, std::less<int>, boost::function<void ()(void*, T)> >::slot_type' is not a type
```

I believe it has something to do with the fact that it's templated, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I've tried adding , such that

```
connection_t connect(signal_t::slot_type<T> subscriber)
```

But this just produceds another error.

Comment: stick a 'typename' keyword in there somewhere - often helps ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tell the compiler that it's a type with `typename`:

```
connection_t connect(typename signal_t::slot_type subscriber){
    return signal.connect(subscriber);
}
```

The problem is that `signal_t` depends on the template parameter `T`, and so you need to explicitly tell the compiler that `signal_t::slot_type` is going to be a type.